# Networking - identical routing tables give different results on two hosts

Tags: routing, vpn, bonding

I have the following puzzle:
There are two hosts, with the routing setup as follows:

```
Host1 (10.40.11.141)
default via 172.27.0.1 dev ovirtmgmt proto static metric 425 
10.40.11.0/24 dev bond1.4011 proto kernel scope link src 10.40.11.141 metric 400 
172.27.0.0/16 dev ovirtmgmt proto kernel scope link src 172.27.4.141 metric 425 
172.28.4.0/24 dev eno8403 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.4.141 metric 100 linkdown

Host2 (10.40.11.181)
default via 172.27.0.1 dev eno8303 metric 425 
10.40.11.0/24 dev team0.4011 proto kernel scope link src 10.40.11.181 metric 400 
172.27.0.0/16 dev eno8303 scope link metric 425 
172.28.0.0/16 dev eno8403 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.4.181 metric 101 linkdown
```

I am connecting by the VPN to the network and I can ping and ssh host1 on both 172.27.4.141 and 10.40.11.141 addresses, but for the Host2 only address 172.27.4.181 is working.

Both can ping and ssh each other through both networks (172.27.4.0 and 10.40.11.0).
When I set the default route on the host2 to be on the 10.40.11.0 network, then I can ping and ssh to interface 10.40.11.181, but not to 172.27.4.181.

I can see no meaningful difference between them except one uses bonding, and the other - teaming for the link aggregation.

Ideally I would like to make host2 to be accessible by both vlans/subnets (like it works with the host1).
How to solve this?

Edit:
There is one difference I have noticed that may be important: oVirt node (10.40.11.141) has a bridge interface ('ovirtmgmt') with IP from mgmt network (172.27.4.141), while in the case of ceph node the address 172.27.4.181 is bound to a physical interface (eno8303).